# Flutter different color for different letters in a Text widget

Tags: text, dart, flutter, widget, textcolor

I have a use-case where I want to change the colour of a letter in a String inside a `Text` widget. Let's say that my String is "Flutter". On pressing the `FloatingActionButton`, I want the letter 'F' to change its colour, then on the next press of the `FloatingActionButton`, change the colour of letter 'l', then 'u', then 't',  then 't', then 'e' and then finally 'r' with every `FloatingActionButton` press.

Please don't suggest having a different `Text` widget for every letter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this using a `RichText` widget and different `TextSpan`s. You can read the documentation to familiarize yourself with it more.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html

Answer (score 5):

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```